# Eclipse cannot launch a project that has been checkout

Tags: eclipse, svn, launch

I am using Eclipse Juno 4.2 an i have checkout a project via Subversive, but i cannot run the project.
I tried using different connectors SVNKit and JavaHL and set the Java build path to working directory, but still cannot launch the program.

I also tried to checkout via Subclipse but with no results.

Comment: If I understand correctlt, then you are able to checkout, but not run your application? Do you get an error? if so, what is it? does the code compile? if not, whats the exception?

Comment: Yes, i can checkout but can't build. Build is disabled. I don't receive an error except that project cannot be run. Eclipse doesn't recognize the project although the project can be seen in Project Explorer

Comment: well, in that case, try building it... It's possible that the project isn't build, so therefor it can't run